# SMTPClient set timout for an open port

Tags: java, smtp, apache-commons

My problem is: I need to discovery if one IP and Port is running a SMTP service.
To do this, I'm using SMTPClient to try open a connection. I'm using the code below.

```
    private static boolean validateSMTP(String ip, int port, int timeOut) {
    SMTPClient smtp = new SMTPClient();

    try {
        smtp.setConnectTimeout(timeOut);            
        smtp.connect(ip, port);
        return true;

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        LogAplication.Warning("Ops... something wrong", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LogAplication.Warning("Ops... something wrong", e);
    }
    finally{
        smtp = null;
    }

    return false;
}
```

It's working fine and I've gotten the expected results, but the timeOut has been my problem. 
E.g: If I try ip: 127.0.0.1 and port 80 (IIS open port) the connect step takes a long (much more than is defined in timeout) to throw an exception

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

How can I set timeOut for this case? Or existis another way to do my simple test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After take a look at [grepCode](http://grepcode.com/), I found this for method [connect(string host, int port)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-net/commons-net/1.4.1/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.java#SocketClient.connect%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29):

> Opens a Socket connected to a remote host at the specified port and
>   originating from the specified local address and port. Before
>   returning, _connect Action() is called to perform connection
>   initialization actions.

As the port is opened by another service, the socket is opened, not causing timeOut (by socket), but the exception was thrown by "connectAction()"
So I needed to set a global timeOut for my SMTPClient, which is used by socket connection and inside of "connectAction()" . And I did this to solve my problem:

```
smtp.setDefaultTimeout(timeOut);
```

With this, now I've the expected results for, open ports which throws exceptions and of course, the successfully connection for SMTP services.

Comment: `smtp.setDefaultTimeout(timeOut);
smtp.setConnectTimeout(timeOut);` 

Both of this line should be there in code ?

Comment: setConnectTimeout: sets the connection timeout in milliseconds, which will be passed to the Socket object's connect() method. 
setDefaultTimeout: sets the default timeout in milliseconds to use when opening a socket.